# Re-arrange an array according to some specific keys - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm a newbie in PHP so please guide me to better practice. Basically, I have this array `$content`, and I would like to change it according to some keys existence. Here's my array :

```
Array
(
    [civilite] => 3
    [first_name] => first_name
    [last_name] => last_name
    [telephone] => xxxxxxxxxxx
    [fax] => xxxxxxxxx
    [telephone_portable] => xxxxxxxxxxxx
    [mail] => example@example.com
    [naissance] => xx/xx/xxx
    [profession] => xxxxxxxxx
    [activite] => 1
    [cb_moto] => 1
    [adresse_moto] => moto 1
    [cp_moto] => xxxxxx 1
    [ville_moto] => xxxxxxxxx
    [moto_permis_1] => A1
    [moto_permis_2] => B1
    [moto_permis_3] => A1
    [moto_marque] => xxxx
    [cb_auto] => 1
    [adresse_auto] => auto 2
    [cp_auto] => xxxxxxxx 2
    [ville_auto] => xxxxxxx
    [auto_permis_1] => A 2
    [auto_permis_2] => B 2
    [auto_permis_3] => A2
    [auto_marque] => xxxx
);
```

And here's what I want to change it to :

```
Array
(
    [general] => Array
                ( 
                [civilite] => 3
                [first_name] => first_name
                [last_name] => last_name
                [telephone] => xxxxxxxxxxx
                [fax] => xxxxxxxxx
                [telephone_portable] => xxxxxxxxxxxx
                [mail] => example@example.com
                [naissance] => xx/xx/xxx
                [profession] => xxxxxxxxx
                [activite] => 1
                )

    [moto] => Array
                ( 
                [cb_moto] => 1
                [adresse_moto] => moto 1
                [cp_moto] => xxxxxx 1
                [ville_moto] => xxxxxxxxx
                [moto_permis_1] => A1
                [moto_permis_2] => B1
                [moto_permis_3] => A1
                [moto_marque] => xxxx
                )

    [auto] => Array
                ( 
                [cb_auto] => 1
                [adresse_auto] => auto 2
                [cp_auto] => xxxxxxxx 2
                [ville_auto] => xxxxxxx
                [auto_permis_1] => A 2
                [auto_permis_2] => B 2
                [auto_permis_3] => A2
                [auto_marque] => xxxx
                )
  );
```

The idea is if the key `cb_moto` exists create a sub-array that has the key `moto` in it until the appearance of the key `cb_auto` and create another sub-array that has the key `auto` and so on.

Here's what I've tried so far :

```
foreach ($content as $key => $value) {
    $content ['general'][] = $value;

    if(isset($_content['cb_moto'])){
        $content ['moto'][] = $value;
    }
}
```

Any help with this? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the key is equal the key name you're looking for, `cb_moto` and `cb_auto` we set a variable to true or false to indicate that and save its data inside its sub-array.

Not the prettier way to achieve it, but easy to follow and readable:

```
<?php
$data = array (
    'civilite' => 3,
    'first_name' => 'first_name',
    'last_name' => 'last_name',
    'telephone' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    'fax' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
    'telephone_portable' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'mail' => 'example@example.com',
    'naissance' => 'xx/xx/xxx',
    'profession' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
    'activite' => 1,
    'cb_moto' => 1,
    'adresse_moto' => 'moto 1',
    'cp_moto' => 'xxxxxx 1',
    'ville_moto' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
    'moto_permis_1' => 'A1',
    'moto_permis_2' => 'B1',
    'moto_permis_3' => 'A1',
    'moto_marque' => 'xxxx',
    'cb_auto' => '1',
    'adresse_auto' => 'auto 2',
    'cp_auto' => 'xxxxxxxx 2',
    'ville_auto' => 'xxxxxxx',
    'auto_permis_1' => 'A 2',
    'auto_permis_2' => 'B 2',
    'auto_permis_3' => 'A2',
    'auto_marque' => 'xxxx'
);

$result = array();

$cb_moto = false;
$cb_auto = false;
foreach ($data as $key => $value)
{
    if($key == 'cb_moto')
    {
        $cb_auto = false;
        $cb_moto = true;
    }

    if($key == 'cb_auto')
    {
        $cb_moto = false;
        $cb_auto = true;
    }

    if ($cb_moto)
    {
        $result['moto'][$key] = $value;
    }
    elseif($cb_auto)
    {
        $result['auto'][$key] = $value;
    }
    else
    {
        $result['general'][$key] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

[**Live DEMO**](https://eval.in/173456)

Using `strpos` instead of variable checks:

```
<?php
$data = array (
    'civilite' => 3,
    'first_name' => 'first_name',
    'last_name' => 'last_name',
    'telephone' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    'fax' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
    'telephone_portable' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'mail' => 'example@example.com',
    'naissance' => 'xx/xx/xxx',
    'profession' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
    'activite' => 1,
    'cb_moto' => 1,
    'adresse_moto' => 'moto 1',
    'cp_moto' => 'xxxxxx 1',
    'ville_moto' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
    'moto_permis_1' => 'A1',
    'moto_permis_2' => 'B1',
    'moto_permis_3' => 'A1',
    'moto_marque' => 'xxxx',
    'cb_auto' => '1',
    'adresse_auto' => 'auto 2',
    'cp_auto' => 'xxxxxxxx 2',
    'ville_auto' => 'xxxxxxx',
    'auto_permis_1' => 'A 2',
    'auto_permis_2' => 'B 2',
    'auto_permis_3' => 'A2',
    'auto_marque' => 'xxxx'
);

$result = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $value)
{
    if (strpos($key, 'moto') !== FALSE)
    {
        $result['moto'][$key] = $value;
    }
    elseif(strpos($key, 'auto') !== FALSE)
    {
        $result['auto'][$key] = $value;
    }
    else
    {
        $result['general'][$key] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

[**Live DEMO**](https://eval.in/173460)

Sample output:

```
Array
(
    [general] => Array
        (
            [civilite] => 3
            [first_name] => first_name
            [last_name] => last_name
            [telephone] => xxxxxxxxxxx
            [fax] => xxxxxxxxx
            [telephone_portable] => xxxxxxxxxxxx
            [mail] => example@example.com
            [naissance] => xx/xx/xxx
            [profession] => xxxxxxxxx
            [activite] => 1
        )

    [moto] => Array
        (
            [cb_moto] => 1
            [adresse_moto] => moto 1
            [cp_moto] => xxxxxx 1
            [ville_moto] => xxxxxxxxx
            [moto_permis_1] => A1
            [moto_permis_2] => B1
            [moto_permis_3] => A1
            [moto_marque] => xxxx
        )

    [auto] => Array
        (
            [cb_auto] => 1
            [adresse_auto] => auto 2
            [cp_auto] => xxxxxxxx 2
            [ville_auto] => xxxxxxx
            [auto_permis_1] => A 2
            [auto_permis_2] => B 2
            [auto_permis_3] => A2
            [auto_marque] => xxxx
        )

)
```

Comment: @user3851013 see the second example its a little bit more simplified.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator (new RecursiveArrayIterator ($content), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $key => $value)
{
    if (strpos ($key, 'moto') === 0)
    {
        $content ['moto'][] = $value;
    } else {
        $content ['general'][] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `strpos` was a nice idea however your sample is wrong needs to be `!== FALSE` and that would only work if all the data in between the area he wants to gather always have `moto` as suffix or prefix like on the sample.

Answer (score 0):

There is the code i made

```
$content = array(   'civilite'              => '3',
                    'first_name'            => 'first_name',
                    'last_name'             => 'last_name',
                    'telephone'             => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
                    'fax'                   => 'xxxxxxxxx',
                    'telephone_portable'    => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
                    'mail'                  => 'example@example.com',
                    'naissance'             => 'xx/xx/xxx',
                    'profession'            => 'xxxxxxxxx',
                    'activite'              => '1',
                    'cb_moto'               => '1',
                    'adresse_moto'          => 'moto 1',
                    'cp_moto'               => 'xxxxxx 1',
                    'ville_moto'            => 'xxxxxxxxx',
                    'moto_permis_1'         => 'A1',
                    'moto_permis_2'         => 'B1',
                    'moto_permis_3'         => 'A1',
                    'moto_marque'           => 'xxxx',
                    'cb_auto'               => '1',
                    'adresse_auto'          => 'auto 2',
                    'cp_auto'               => 'xxxxxxxx 2',
                    'ville_auto'            => 'xxxxxxx',
                    'auto_permis_1'         => 'A 2',
                    'auto_permis_2'         => 'B 2',
                    'auto_permis_3'         => 'A2',
                    'auto_marque'           => 'xxxx'
                );

$moto = array();
$auto = array();
$gene = array();

foreach( $content as $k => $v ){

    if( preg_match('/auto/', $k) ){

        $auto[$k] = $v;
    }
    elseif( preg_match('/moto/', $k) ){

        $moto[$k] = $v;
    }
    else{

        $gene[$k] = $v;
    }
}

$content = array();

if( !empty($gene) ){
    $content['general'] = $gene;
}
if( !empty($auto) && isset($auto['cb_auto']) ){
    $content['auto'] = $auto;
}
if( !empty($moto) && isset($moto['cb_moto']) ){
    $content['moto'] = $moto;
}

var_dump($content);
```

Comment: Why use regex? [Why.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) [why.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) [whyyyyyyyyy](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/113243/108554)

Comment: ahaha :p i didn't know for str functions ^^ now i know, THX <3